# Use of watch and lsof + grep together

Tags: grep, watch, lsof

When i use

```
lsof -p 3536693 | grep snapshot
```

I get an output

but if i try to

```
watch lsof -p 3536693 | grep snapshot
```

I get nothing. Aren't they compatible?

It works if I ommit grep, like

```
watch lsof -p 3536693
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when the "watched" command is quoted, so:

```
watch "lsof -p 3536693 | grep snapshot"
```